# Can I query for Estimates with NULL ClassRef in Quickbooks API v3?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

According to the documents, you should be able to query for NULL `ClassRef` values like so:

```
select * from Estimate where ClassRef = ' '
```

But, that query is causing a validation error:

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "Error": [
      {
        "Message": "Invalid ID",
        "Detail": "Id should be a valid number. Supplied value: ",
        "code": "2030",
        "element": "ClassRef"
      }
    ],
    "type": "ValidationFault"
  },
  "time": "2014-06-19T12:34:43.37-07:00"
}
```

How can I query for null `ClassRef`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't search by ClassRef because it is not a filterable attribute for the Estimate entity.

References:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/estimate
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations